Proving that deterministic and stateless encryption scheme cannot achieve indistinguishability of multiple encryptions
Typically a deterministic encryption scheme is characterized by the lack of randomness: a message $m$ will alawys be encrypted to the same ciphertext $c$.
A stateful encryption scheme keeps track of a state that can be initialized differently (but not necessarily randomly) at the beginning of each encryption (e.g. using an initialization vector (IV) such as in CBC). A message $m$ can therefore be encrypted to different ciphertexts $c$.
With that in mind, I want to try and prove that if an encryption scheme is deterministic and stateless then it cannot achieve indistinguishability of multiple encryptions under the presence of an adversary A.
I am not sure how to do this and am looking for pointers. Below follows my attempt.

Let's play the game of indistinguishability under chosen plaintext attack (IND-CPA). We allow the adversary to see encryptions of any messages of its choice. Meaning, the adversary can send multiple messages one at a time and receive their encryptions before making a guess. I believe that the upper limit of the number of queries the adversary can do is supposed to be proportional to $2^x$ for some large $x$. However, I am not sure about the details of that. The point of the upper limit comes from the fact that we assume an efficient adversary that can make progress in polynomial time. We do not consider adversaries that have an infinite amount of time on their hands.
We define a symmetric encryption scheme $SE = (K,E,D)$ where $K$ is a key generation function, $E$ is an encryption function, and $D$ a decryption function.

The challenger uniformly draws a key $k \leftarrow \\\$K$.

The adversary $A$ sends a number of messages $M_i$ to the challenger one at a time.

The challenger returns $C_i = E(k, M_i)$ to the adversary for every received $M_i$.

When the adversary is ready to make a guess, he sends to the challenger two messages $M_0$ and $M_1$ whose ciphertexts he is to distinguish.

The challenger draws $b \leftarrow \\\$\{0,1\}$ and sends back $c = E(k, M_b)$.

The adversary makes a guess $b'$ and wins iff $b' == b$.


In order to prove that the mentioned encryption scheme is not secure, the adversary must come up with an attack strategy such that it yields a non-neglible advantage in correctly guessing $b'=b$. This essentially means that the adversary must be able to do non-negligbly better than just randomly guessing.
The adversary knows that the encryption scheme is deterministic. The adversary can make several queries where at least two of the queries are for the same message. He'd then notice that a message is encrypted to the same ciphertext.
So, the strategy is then to send two messages $(M_0^*, M_1^*)$ where $M_0^*$ is the message we queried for twice earlier in the game, and $M_1^*$ is something else.
When the challenger sends back $C_b^* = E(k,M_b^*)$, if $C_b^* = C_0^*$ the adversary guesses $b'=0$, otherwise $b'=1$.
The adversary can as such with 100% certainty correctly guess $b'=b$.

Note that I have assumed a symmetric encryption scheme. The case of an asymmetric encryption scheme is easier I believe. The adversary can simply send two arbitrary messages, and after having received a ciphertext for one of the messages from the challenger simply evaluate $E(pk,m_0)$ and see if it matches with the received ciphertext. If they match then guess $b'=0$ else $b'=1$.
